# Compiling a project with libcurl in cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, compilation, libcurl

I am not entirely sure how to compile a file with cygwin so it links with libcurl properly. I installed the libcurl library with cygwin's package installer so I don't think there's anything wrong with that I'm just not sure what the syntax for the command will be. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like `gcc -Wall -o curluser curluser.c -lcurl` should work.  Similar to linking math library with `-lm`.

Or, what did you try so far and what happened and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Aha! I figured it out, it turns out I'm an idiot and installed libcurl incorrectly...duh! Thanks for your help though!